# SFTP via Paramiko to ipv6 linux machine

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, paramiko

I am relatively new to python and am trying sftp for the first time via python script. I want my python script to get a file from a **Dual Stack Machine (Both IPv4 and IPv6 present)**. Below is the code snippet I am using for Paramiko:

```
host = ip #ip is a string that has the value of IP
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport
```

When I use the code with IPv4 it works fine. But when I replace the ip with IPv6 address, following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MyFile.py", line 92, in <module>
putFile()
File "MyFile.py", line 29, in analyzeLogs
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 289, in __init__
sock.connect((hostname, port))
File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I checked for a solution and found someone suggesting to add the interface along with the IP but while trying the same I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MyFile.py", line 92, in <module>
putFile()
File "MyFile.py", line 29, in analyzeLogs
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 289, in __init__
sock.connect((hostname, port))
File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.gaierror: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported
```

My original server will not be a dual stack machine and hence I need the file transfer via IPv6 only.

**NOTE**:When I use sftp command in linux, it works for both ipv4 and ipv6

Any possible solution or additional suggestions would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paramiko's `Transport` class supports passing in a socket object as well as a tuple. So maybe try specifically passing in an ipv6 socket?

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((hostname, port))
transport = paramiko.Transport(sock)
```

Comment: Hi, does this require the sock.close() method to be called or it closes automatically with transport.close().

Comment: [`Transport.close()`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/5cc85375ca094b398f20acc9f978b88a6d7a9ef4/paramiko/transport.py#L648) will close the socket for you.